# Drawing dynamically n plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am writing measurement program and matplotlib is used to display measurement values as they are obtained.  I figured out how to do that for single plot, i.e.

```
x=[0,1,2]
y=[3,5,7]
set_xdata(x)
set_ydata(y)
```

Each time x and y change, I call `set_xdata` and `set_ydata` and refresh graph.

However, I want to plot dynamically `n` y values against single x value, i.e.

```
x=[0,1,2]
y=[[3,5,7],[4,6,8],[5,7,9]]
```

Is that possible to do that, knowing `n` (number of y plots)?

EDIT:

I am interested in two things:

1. How to just refresh data of multiplot instead of completely redrawing plot each time data change?
2. Does matplotlib support multiple Y data against single X data plotting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell: you have to create a `Line2D` instance for each "plot". 
And slightly more elaborative:

1. As you have done it with a single line, you can also do the same with multiple lines:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   # initial values
   x = [0,1,2]
   y = [[3,5,7],[4,6,8],[5,7,9]]

   # create the line instances and store them in a list
   line_objects = list()
   for yi in y:
       line_objects.extend(plt.plot(x, yi))

   # new values with which we want to update the plot
   x = [1,2,3]
   y = [[4,6,8],[5,7,9],[6,8,0]]

   # update the y values dynamically (without recreating the plot)        
   for yi, line_object in zip(y, line_objects):
       line_object.set_xdata(x)
       line_object.set_ydata(yi)
   ```
2. Not really. However, you can create mulitple `Line2D` objects by a single call to `plot`:

   ```
   line_objects = plt.plot(x, y[0], x, y[1], x, y[2])
   ```

   That is also why `plot` always returns a list.

#### EDIT:

If you have to do this often, it might help to use helper functions:

E.g.:

```
def plot_multi_y(x, ys, ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    return [ax.plot(x, y, **kwargs)[0] for y in ys]

def update_multi_y(line_objects, x, ys):
    for y, line_object in zip(ys, line_objects):
        line_object.set_xdata(x)
        line_object.set_ydata(y)
```

Then you can just use:

```
# create the lines
line_objects = plot_multi_y(x, y)

#update the lines
update_multi_y(line_objects, x, y)
```

Comment: OK, I was thinking about this solution myself, but I posted my question in order to find out if there is any more intuitive solution.  (multiple y against single x is quite common option in graph drawing programs).

Comment: Yeah, I can see your point. That's probably a feature which would be nice to have.